# SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked

Tags: android, sqlite

SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

I am getting this exception while debugging the app

Answer (score 0):

You will need to close the DatabaseHelper connection after using it. Missing to close them may create this exception,

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
db.open();
...
...
...
db.close();
}
```